# Python method works if we replace self with random object , why and how?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, methods

In the code below you can see my questions in the comments, when I call the methods of the class with the first argument with a random object instead of the instance test, it still works!
Why doen't throw error and how it works under the hood?

```
class Classtest():
    def instance_method(self):
        print(f'Called instance_method of {self}.')

   def d(self, a):
       print(2*a)


test = Classtest()

Classtest.instance_method(test) 
# output: Called instance_method of <__main__.Classtest object at 0x0085F070>.
Classtest.instance_method("kokokoko")
#output: Called instance_method of kokokoko.    #why??? and why not error???
Classtest.d(test,4) 
#output:8
Classtest.d("tralala",4)
#output:8 #why??? and why and how it works?
```

Comment: When you call an instance method directly on the class, whatever argument you pass goes into `self`. That's how function parameters work.

Comment: Duck typing, you're calling a class from method passing a variable to self, this is in fact useful, it let you do things like this `[str.upper(x) for x in ['foo', 'bar']]`

Comment: Because `Classtest.d` is simply a regular function, methods only get created when you access them through instances via the descriptor protocol, that is, function objects are descriptors

Comment: To add on to @juanpa.arrivillaga's comment (which is entirely correct for Python 3), this hasn't always been the case. In Python 2, when you accessed a method via a class (e.g. `ClassTest.instance_method`), you'd get an unbound method object. That object would do a type check on the first argument when it was called, and so you'd get errors in all the cases where you expected to in the question. But the type check wasn't all that useful really, since most methods called with unexpected objects as `self` will fail anyway, so it was taken out for Python 3, and you just get the normal function.

Answer (score 0):

You've gone to extra work to bypass the normal operation of a class method.  Instead of using the invocation syntax you found in your educational materials

```
test.instancemethod()
test.d(4)
```

... you've called each method as a *class* method and overridden the symbiont object for the call.  Since your methods don't actually use the class instance that invokes them, you "get away with" this usage.

For instance, when you call `d`, you've hard-coded a string as the `self` object, but then you don't use it in any illegal fashion.  The method happily prints the value of 2*4.

I suggest that you work through another tutorial or two on classes and methods to get the hang of how they're intended to work.  **Then** you're in a good position to bend the intentions this way.  :-)